# Csv file ingestion from hdfs to hive

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am trying to ingest the csv file from my hdfs to hive using the command below.

```
create table test (col1 string, col2 int, col3 string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("separatorChar" = ",","quoteChar" = "\"")
stored as textfile;
```

But I am still getting double quotes in my hive table, so I tried the command below.

```
alter table test
set TBLPROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count'='1','serialization.null.format' = '');
```

But still getting double quotes. What can I do to remove these double quotes?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the file location.
For example:
`CREATE TABLE test (col1 string, col2 int, col3 string) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("separatorChar" = ",") 
STORED AS textfile
LOCATION 'hdfs://<your-data-node-address>:8020/hdfs/path/to/csv/files-dir';`
When I create the table this way I don't have quotes on the values in my table (the source csv file does have)